# Manga involving characters with numbers on the backs of their hands

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It is an isekai, I believe. The last chapters I remember reading involved the main character (MC) fighting against enemies who had numbers on the back of their hands, that indicated how strong they were.

The MC proceeds to defeat a triple-digit enemy. The enemy's sister is a double-digit agent that can control people and morph them.

The MC is in a village where the village head or member is captured by the double-digit enemy and the MC proceeds to fight, and then shows that he was actually part of that group and has the 0 digit on the back of his hand.

Edit:
It was a black and white
I'm pretty sure it's japanese manga.
I don't remember which site I used to read it.
I don't recall any names (I thought I would be able to remember it and see it as it updated).
I don't remember if MC fought barehanded or with a weapon. I want to say he did use magic since the double digit enemy could not control him

There are fantasy creatures.
MC was traveling with a group but did not reveal anything about him having a number.
Manga is not Plunderer, numbers don't correlate with death, the last few chapters I read was when the number concept was introduced.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, did the MC fight unarmed, or with a weapon, or with magic?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: The concept of a higher Count being stronger sounds similar to [Plunderer](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37345/Plunderer), but it isn't really an isekai and the MC's count was negative, not 0. The other incidents also vaguely correspond to some events, but doesn't feel like a strong enough match without more details or confirmation.

Comment: The "numbers" are basically a secret society or something the MC is a part of, and this isn't revealed at first, correct? Do you know about when the numbers start showing up, i.e. what chapter number? Or about when you read this arc? Do you remember anything about earlier parts of the story, particularly the overall synopsis or the first few chapters? Those are the easiest to search for.

Comment: I don't recall anything else unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you are talking about ***[Shijou Saikyou no Mahou Kenshi](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/7hiinvz/shijou-saikyou-no-mahou-kenshi-f-rank-boukensha-ni-tensei-suru-kensei-to-matei-2-tsu-no-zense-omotta-otoko-no-eiyuutan)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Aizawa Yuri has reincarnated two times now and is dead tired of being the emperor of this and that. Using his skills he acquired a reincarnation artifact, and starts his life in a brand new world!

The MC does reveal he's the zero-digit during his fight with a three-digit from that group. He then deals with the second three-digit during a request to kill an undead dragon. The two-digit, the sister to the second three-digit, he meets during a quest to slay ogres, where it's found she was controlling/turning them into monsters. The MC fought with sword and magic and tamed monsters.